# Should time and status in survival analysis be included in imputation process of MissForest?

Tags: missing-data, survival-analysis, imputation

In regression and classification tasks, it seems common to include the response with other covariates when using missForest to impute the covariates. However, how about the time and status of survival analysis? Is there any way to account for the censoring?